# Laravel 5 stage server 403 on / route

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

Even though I already have `Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');` inside `routes.php`, when I access `myherokuappurl.heroku.com` (this is not the real url) it shows a 403 error.

The `WelcomeController` is the scaffolded one by artisan, it contains:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

public function index() {
    return view('welcome');
}
```

Any ideas? using laravel 5

**Edit:** it works fine on my *Laravel/Homestead* development environment

**Update 1:** these are my heroku web server setup

```
// Procfile
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/

// nginx.conf
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**Update 2**: The 403 only happens on `/` route, but on `/myresource/index` or `/myresource/create` works fine

Comment: folder permissions, htaccess configuration, `myherokuappurl.heroku.com` poiting to the root instead of pointing to your public folder, etc.. It can be so many things

Comment: You need write permissions on your `storage` folder.

Comment: Hello, I already tried 777-ing the entire app but still same error